# CSS Middle div height

Tags: css, html

i have the following css http://jsbin.com/azivip/75/edit i would like to have the yellow div height to fill the space between the blue and green divs. using height inherit seems to make the div goes beyond the green div.

Any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: Does it has to be cross-browser solution?

Comment: not necessary no, if it's cross browser it's better however if it works with chrome/firefox it's enough

Comment: so you can use css3 `calc()`: `#testsContainer { height: calc(100% -140px;)}` `140px = 100px of resultsContainer + 40px of buttonsContainer`

Comment: Can you specify the heights of the three inner containers in percentages rather than pixels?

Answer (score 5):

You can use css3 `calc()`:

```
#testsContainer { 
   height: calc(100% - 140px);
}
```

Where `140px = 100px of resultsContainer + 40px of buttonsContainer`

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/azivip/79/edit)

**EDIT**

For older versions of Firefox use `-moz-calc()` prefix, for older versions of Chrome/Safari use `-webkit-calc()` prefix.

Comment: This only appears to work in IE9. You can make it work in Firefox by using the -moz- prefix: `height: -moz-calc(100% - 140px);`

Comment: This is only for older versions of Firefox. Use `-webkit-calc` for older chrome and safari. All latest version browsers are not using prefixes.

Comment: great thanks guys! with firefox it seems to be working fine, any idea what could be done to handle chrome if possible? chrome doesn't seem to support calc()

Comment: Morpheus is correct, you can use -webkit-calc for v25 of Chrome (latest) and no prefix for forthcoming v26: http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: @All, it should be noted the lack of support elsewhere (IE8, IE7, Opera, mobile browsers). This is nowhere near reliable at the minute as those browsers together account for a large percentage of the market share. Please make sure you have a fallback.

Comment: As of author comment `if it's cross browser it's better however if it works with chrome/firefox it's enough ` I will happily upvote cross-browser solution, if there will be posted any :)

Answer (score 4):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsbin.com/azivip/93/edit)**

Just change the following css in your code:

```
 #testsContainer {
     position:absolute; /* replace with position: relative */
     top:100px;  /* height of the above container */
     bottom:40px; /* height of the below container */
     left:0px;
     right:0px;
     margin-top:0px;
     margin-bottom:0px;
     background-color:yellow; 
 }
```

- Give `top` value equal to the height of the `div#resultsContainer` and `bottom` value equal to the height of the `div#buttonsContainer`.
- Give `left: 0` and `right:0`. So that the container can occupy the space without using the support of javascript or calc() css property.
- Remove `height:inherit`
- Replace `position: relative` with `position: absolute`

Comment: @chris Please mark it as answer if my post solved your problem. :)